# Тестирование интерфейса Xamarin.iOS приложения

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Помогите разобратся с вопросов - как тестировать интерфейсы кросплатформенных приложений на `Xamarin` под `iOS`? Есть `Xamarin.Forms` решение. Я пишу для него кросплатформенный  `Xamarin.UI Test` используя Visual Studio под Windows. С андроид проблем нет - запустил симулятор, начал тест. С `iOS` сложнее - подключаюсь к удаленному mac, запускаю на нем симулятор устройства с `ios`, на симуляторе запускаю приложение - нормально работает, а вот тесты не запускаются:

> iOS tests are not supported on Windows

Посмотрел в сторону `Visual Studio App Center` но в данном сервисе решение собирается в облаке с использованием исходного кода, что на настоящий момент нежелательно. В общем, какие могут быть варианты, необходимо ли устанавливать на `mac` `Xamarin Studio` ?

Comment: Нашли какое-то решение? :)

Comment: @Максим нашлось только 2 решения либо mac и VS под него либо app center

Comment: А Xamarin Live Player не рассматривали?